# Reading out a FLIR Blackfly Gige S camera with Python

Tags: camera, ethernet, pyspin

I am building a low cost spectrometer and want to use a jupyter notebook to controll the camera and analyse the data. I am using a FLIR Blackfly Gige S and I connect it to my PC using a Lan cable and a USB-C adapter. I have tried to download PySpin and install it but the process has problems with the metadata. I suspect that it is due to me using Python 3.11. and PySpin only supporting up to 3.10. I did manage to install Spinnaker SDK and use Spinview to read out the camera signal without problem. If anybody knows any solution to my problem, please let me know.

I tried to use OpenCV and other methodes to read out the camera instead but it was not sucessfull.Installing a new python version is difficult because I do not have administrative rights for that PC and would need to contact our IT for this.